# Mysql subquery run slow on live server but fast on local

Tags: mysql, subquery, database-performance

I have a pretty simple query, that on my local windows machine takes 0.04 sec but on our live server that is a linux machine it needs 30 seconds!

Anyone familiar with the same problem?

This is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
s.carId FROM
cardetail_search s WHERE
s.carId IN (SELECT DISTINCT c.carId FROM carid id JOIN car c ON c.carId = id.carId WHERE id.ProductNumber = 'pnumber' OR id.ProductNumber = 'pnumber2')
    AND pictureTableId IN (SELECT DISTINCT pictureTableId FROM cardetail WHERE ProductNumber = 'pnumber' OR ProductNumber = 'pnumber2')
```

EDIT: any subquery runs slow

SOLUTION: instead of subqueries that use COLUMN IN() when I use INNER JOIN it works as expected. Check the approved answer for the refactored query.

Comment: Sounds like you have less data in your local database as in the Server db

Comment: The data is exactly the same

Comment: Have you compared the ddl's?

Comment: Sorry, what do u mean by comparing dlls?

Comment: What i mean is that you should compare if the table create Statements are the same. (same datatypes, same Indexes, ...)

Comment: Yes they are :) I use other queries on the same tables to and they all work great, but when it comes to subqueries it is extremely slow on live, and not only this particular subquery but any.

Comment: same db Version and configuration?

Comment: local: 5.7.17  (win64)
server: 5.5.57 (debian x86_64)

Comment: Could be caused by a lot of different reasons. Are your DB structures identical on both servers ? are your mysql servers identical ? have you tried EXPLAIN on both servers ?

Comment: @bonbonvoyage different db Versions can have different optimizer, so this can be the Problem. Use `EXPLAIN` to see how the query works in both databases.

Comment: @Jens I have tried explain now, and they look very different. First I have to learn how to read it tough, ill come back to you when I can comment on it :) Thanks again for help

Comment: @alpadev I tried EXPLAIN now and it looks very different. Ill come back when I can comment on it :)

Comment: Thanks for help, please check the accepted answer. I am happy with the solution, I think in all cases I can avoid using COLUMN IN().

Comment: Show us the `EXPLAIN` from each server.  What MySQL versions are you running?  (There have been Optimization changes in this area.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comments, I can think "statistics" on dbs are different.
You can try this and see if you obtain better performance (db engine can prepare different plan when using INNER JOIN vs COLUMN IN (...) :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
s.carId
FROM cardetail_search s 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT c.carId FROM carid id 
            INNER JOIN car c ON c.carId = id.carId 
            WHERE id.ProductNumber = 'pnumber' OR id.ProductNumber = 'pnumber2') X ON s.carID = X.carID
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT pictureTableId FROM cardetail WHERE ProductNumber = 'pnumber' OR ProductNumber = 'pnumber2') Y ON s.pictureTableId = Y.pictureTableId
```

Comment: WOW, it works perfect! Thanks alot. I guess I will avoid using COLUMN IN in the future :)

Comment: I would up vote your answer to, but i am a rookie here so cant yet :(. You saved me a lot of time, thanks a bunch!!

Comment: about your " I will avoid using COLUMN IN in the future", do it with care.  Sometime IN can be faster.  For instance, in MSSQL (as far as I remember)  you could have some advantage if number of result from inner select are just a few.  Moral: give always a look at explain plan of execution.

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause for this discrepancy is that you have a different configuration for caching subqueries and mysql is creating temporary tables on disk on the linux server.
This process takes a long time and its not very efficient. You can increase the amount of memory alloted before mysql decides to create a temporary table in disk  by modifying the maximum size of temporary tables on memory:

Look at the configuration on this 2 variables and consider increasing them.

- tmp_table_size
- max_heap_table_size

Comment: Looks okay :/ Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Mentioning `car` seems unnecessary?

```
SELECT DISTINCT carId
    FROM  cardetail_search AS s
    JOIN  carid AS cid     ON s.carId = cid.carId
    JOIN  cardetail AS cd  ON s.pictureTableId = cd.pictureTableId
    WHERE  cid.ProductNumber IN (...)
      AND  cd.ProductNumber  IN (...)
```

Or, maybe you intended for the ProductNumber to match...

```
SELECT DISTINCT carId
    FROM  cardetail_search AS s
    JOIN  carid AS cid     ON s.carId = cid.carId
    JOIN  cardetail AS cd  ON s.pictureTableId = cd.pictureTableId
    WHERE  cid.ProductNumber IN (...)
      AND  cd.ProductNumber = cid.ProductNumber
```

Don't increase `tmp_table_size` past about 1% of RAM.  Else you risk blowing out RAM in extreme cases.

`IN ( SELECT ... )` used to be terribly inefficient.

`FROM ( SELECT ... ) JOIN ( SELECT ... )` is currently inefficient because neither subquery has any indexes.

Comment: About the car, I forgot to delete it out before posting.. removed some fields from select for easier reading.. Thanks for the answer! :)